# Cant run integration test because of IllegalStateException in grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, integration-testing, spock

I am using Grails 2.4.4 for my application. I wrote an integration test for my controller.

```
class UserControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    UserController controller = new UserController()

    void "test something"() {
        when:
        controller.request.method = 'POST'
        controller.create()

        then:
        controller.response.status == HttpStatus.OK.value()
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run tests with IntelliJ I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find ApplicationContext, configure Grails correctly first
    at grails.util.Holders.getApplicationContext(Holders.java:97)
    at grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec.$spock_initializeSharedFields(IntegrationSpec.groovy:41)
```

When I am running integration test using console with `test-app` command there is no problem. P.S. unit tests are working without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run an integration test in isolation in an IDE like you can with unit tests. The integration test environment has almost as much running as then you run with `run-app`, with the one big difference being that there's no web server.

So the testing infrastructore expects there to be a Spring Application context (at least in part so dependency injection will work for test classes), GORM, plugins, etc. So you can run integration tests from the IDE, but they have to just run `grails test-app` and capture the output for you, much like when you run the app in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the issue at-hand, but commenting on the above, I believe I'm able to execute integration tests in isolation, within intellij.

Not sure what yr setup was, here's mine roughly:

- grails 2.4.4
- intellij IDEA ultimate 13.1.5

Steps to repro:

1. grails create-app foo (+cd foo/)
2. grails create-domain-class com.foo.User
3. grails generate-restful-controller com.foo.User
4. test:

   ```
   package com.foo

   import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
   import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus

   class UserControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

       UserController controller = new UserController()

       void "test something"() {
           when:
           controller.request.method = 'POST'
           controller.save()

           then:
           controller.response.status == HttpStatus.OK.value()
       }

   }
   ```
5. executed with ctrl+shift+f10 (Run Context Configuration), cursor positioned within the method in-question.

The result of the test:

```
|Running 1 integration test...

|Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
--Output from test something--
Failure:  |
test something(com.foo.UserControllerIntegrationSpec)
 |
Condition not satisfied:

controller.response.status == HttpStatus.OK.value()
...
```

Here's a snippet from `.idea/workspace.xml` that seems to be describing the test configuration:

```
<configuration default="false" name="test something()" type="GrailsRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Grails">
  <module name="foo" />
  <setting name="vmparams" value="-Dgrails.full.stacktrace=true" />
  <setting name="cmdLine" value="test-app integration: &quot;com.foo.UserControllerIntegrationSpec.test something&quot; -echoOut" />
  <setting name="depsClasspath" value="false" />
  <setting name="passParentEnv" value="true" />
  <extension name="coverage" enabled="false" merge="false" sample_coverage="true" runner="idea" />
  <setting name="launchBrowser" value="false" />
  <RunnerSettings RunnerId="Run" />
  <ConfigurationWrapper RunnerId="Run" />
  <method />
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps